# Как заставить select запоминать выбранную позицию?

Tags: html, php

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой: через `<select>` выводится информация из бд, выбрав ее мы переходим по ссылке на опр. страницу, на которой также установлен данный селект, но в нем снова отображается первая строка выбора, а не та (название страницы), на которой мы находимся в данный момент, как это можно исправить?

Код формы:

```
<form name="seria_name"  method="POST" action="/template/seria_redirect.php">';?> 
<select name="seria_name" onchange="document.forms.seria_name.submit();return false">
<?php
$query_seria = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT seria_name, id_seria FROM serias WHERE id_sezon = '$id_sezon'");
while ($row_seria = mysqli_fetch_array($query_seria)) {
echo ' 
    <option value="' . $row_seria['id_seria'] . '">' . $row_seria['seria_name'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>
</form>';
```

Код обработчика:

```
if (isset($_POST['seria_name'])) {
    $id_seria    = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['seria_name']));
    $query_seria = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT id_sezon, id_serial FROM serias WHERE id_seria = '$id_seria'");
    $row_seria   = mysqli_fetch_array($query_seria);
    $id_sezon    = $row_seria['id_sezon'];
    $id_serial   = $row_seria['id_serial'];
    header('Location: /index.php?id=' . $id_serial . '&id_sezon=' . $id_sezon . '&id_seria=' . $id_seria);
}
```

Comment: Выделите код как положено, читать невозможно. Потом поговорим о проблеме

Comment: позицию хранить в переменной =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form name="seria_name"  method="POST" action="/template/seria_redirect.php">';?> 
<select name="seria_name" onchange="document.forms.seria_name.submit();return false">
<?php
$query_seria = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT seria_name, id_seria FROM serias WHERE id_sezon = '$id_sezon'");
$id_seria = (isset($_GET['id_seria']) && is_numeric($_GET['id_seria'])) ? $_GET['id_seria'] : 0;
while ($row_seria = mysqli_fetch_array($query_seria)) {
$selected=(!empty($id_seria) && $id_seria==$row_seria['id_seria']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
echo ' 
    <option '.$selected.' value="' . $row_seria['id_seria'] . '">' . $row_seria['seria_name'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>
</form>';
```

Comment: ругается на эту строку:
$id_seria = (isset($_GET['id_seria'] && is_numeric($_GET['id_seria']))) ? $_GET['id_seria'] : 0;

syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: нет ( не выводится в селекте... так же как было

Comment: Омг, скобки посчитайте)))
$id_seria = (isset($_GET['id_seria']) && is_numeric($_GET['id_seria'])) ? $_GET['id_seria'] : 0;

И причем вообще $_POST если он через header передает id_seria?? Ну вы гоните)))

Answer (score 1):

Поправил ответ предыдущего оратора.

```
    <form name="seria_name"  method="POST" action="/template/seria_redirect.php">
    <select name="seria_name" onchange="document.forms.seria_name.submit();return false">
    <?php
    $query_seria = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT seria_name, id_seria FROM serias WHERE id_sezon = '$id_sezon'");
    while ($row_seria = mysqli_fetch_array($query_seria)) {
   $selected = (isset($_GET['id_seria'])&&($_GET['id_seria']==$row_seria['id_seria']))? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '
        <option value="' . $row_seria['id_seria'] . '" '.$selected.' >' . $row_seria['seria_name'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>
    </form>';
    ?>
```

Comment: `$selected = ($_POST['seria_name'] == $row_seria['id_seria']) 'selected="selected"' : '';`

>syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: $_POST['seria_name'] == $row_seria['id_seria']) этого не будет никогда, имя и id это разные вещи). И скобочку забыли кстати

Comment: потерял `?` после условия

Comment: и это тоже

Comment: все то же( селект не выводит текущую страницу

Comment: замечательная иллюстрация пословицы "поспешишь - людей насмешишь".

мне урок.

Comment: да он и не будет выводить))) вы передаете id через header в своем обработчике - header('Location: /index.php?id=' . $id_serial . '&id_sezon=' . $id_sezon . '&id_seria=' . $id_seria);
header впринципе не может передавать $_POST, это первое. Второе как можно сравнивать $_POST['seria_name'] и $row_seria['id_seria']). Это же разные вещи. Возьмите мой первый пример и там где тернарный оператор проверьте скобку, я в комментах написал

Comment: а посмотреть можно?

Comment: я исправил мой ответ. смотрите

Comment: Спасибо ребята за помощь!

Comment: @ANTiK, учитесь искать проблему сами. Было же очевидно написано что нехватает скобки или запятой, да еще и строка указана в какой нет. Если не научитесь, то грош цена такому программисту, который за каждую ошибку будет на форум писать))